Getting an error: After updating TeX Live 2024, 'Argument of \NewSocket has an extra }' when using tagpdf.sty with disable option
"Getting an error: After updating TeX Live 2024 today, Argument of \NewSocket has an extra } appears when using tagpdf.sty with \disable@package@load{tagpdf}{}.
I used Lualatex-dev.exe (texlive 2024) for compiling a file.

MWE:
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{tagpdf}{}
\makeatother
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,table,pdfversion = 2.0}}
\tagpdfsetup{role/map-tags=pdf}
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
Sample text
\end{document}

Why are you disabling the loading of tagpdf??

you start by disabling a core part of the  tagging code, then explicitly load the tagging code with \DocumentMetadata what do you expect this to do?

In one file, I am getting the error 'The number of automatic begin (3) and end (2)'. I am unable to identify the issue. In the .cls file, I have used \tagstructbegin and \tagmcbegin in some places, so I decided to use \disable@package@load{tagpdf}{}.
The same file compiled without any errors when the option was disabled, but after upgrading TeX Live today, I am now facing the issue and cannot resolve it by me."

sorry but this is nonsense. If you don't load tagpdf you don't get tagging, so phase-III is useless. You need to debug the error (the most common reason for it is a \vbox that doesn't correctly ends with a \par).

The first three lines completely break the tagging code, and so no good result can happen if you enable tagging in \DocumentMetadata
Deleting those lines, the document runs without error.
but with
LaTeX DocumentMetadata Warning: LaTeX-lab package 'pdfversion = 2.0' not
(DocumentMetadata)              found.

LaTeX DocumentMetadata Warning: The language has not been set in
(DocumentMetadata)              \DocumentMetadata.
(DocumentMetadata)              Setting it to 'en' as fallback.


as lang=en is missing and the pdfstandard key should not be in testphase, so
\DocumentMetadata{
lang=en,pdfversion = 2.0,
testphase={phase-III,table}
}

\tagpdfsetup{role/map-tags=pdf}

\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

Sample text

\end{document}

